# Python selenium find checkbox

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to find check box and click in it. I've tried using:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(("//*[contains(text(), '2+ interchanges')]")).click()
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('BpkCheckbox_bpk-checkbox__label__1vrLS BpkCheckbox_bpk-checkbox__label--small__16XBT')
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_name('2+ interchanges').click()
```

but no luck, always get error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element:
```

Could you please give me some advice how i do should find this checkbox?

Thanks!

Best

The code looks like:

```html
    <div class="Filter_verticallySpaced__1Sm6F Filter_horizontallySpaced__RwfGp FiltersCheckboxes_colourOnHover__erAw_">
     <label class="BpkCheckbox_bpk-checkbox__2yTOQ FiltersCheckboxes_checkboxLine__7IQLY">
      <input aria-invalid="false" aria-label="2+ interchanges" checked="" class="BpkCheckbox_bpk-checkbox__input__2qMb7" name="twoPlusStops" type="checkbox"/>
      <svg class="BpkCheckbox_bpk-checkbox__icon__1KuPa" height="18" style="width: 0.75rem; height: 0.75rem;" viewbox="0 0 24 24" width="18" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
       <path d="M9.4 20c-.5 0-.9-.2-1.3-.5l-5.8-5.1c-.4-.4-.5-1-.1-1.4l1.3-1.5c.4-.4 1-.5 1.4-.1l4 3.5c.2.1.4.1.6 0l9.2-10.5c.4-.4 1-.5 1.4-.1l1.5 1.3c.4.4.5 1 .1 1.4L10.9 19.3c-.4.5-.9.7-1.5.7z">
       </path>
      </svg>
      <span aria-hidden="true" class="BpkCheckbox_bpk-checkbox__label__1vrLS BpkCheckbox_bpk-checkbox__label--small__16XBT">
       2+ interchanges
      </span>
     </label>
     <span class="BpkText_bpk-text__2NHsO BpkText_bpk-text--sm__345aT FiltersCheckboxes_subText__3aG9- FiltersCheckboxes_block__1ZTpQ FiltersCheckboxes_checkboxIndent__2c49O">
      2 735 $
     </span>
    </div>
<div class="Filter_verticallySpaced__1Sm6F Filter_horizontallySpaced__RwfGp FiltersCheckboxes_colourOnHover__erAw_">
 <label class="BpkCheckbox_bpk-checkbox__2yTOQ FiltersCheckboxes_checkboxLine__7IQLY">
  <input aria-invalid="false" aria-label="1 interchange" checked="" class="BpkCheckbox_bpk-checkbox__input__2qMb7" name="oneStop" type="checkbox"/>
  <svg class="BpkCheckbox_bpk-checkbox__icon__1KuPa" height="18" style="width: 0.75rem; height: 0.75rem;" viewbox="0 0 24 24" width="18" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <path d="M9.4 20c-.5 0-.9-.2-1.3-.5l-5.8-5.1c-.4-.4-.5-1-.1-1.4l1.3-1.5c.4-.4 1-.5 1.4-.1l4 3.5c.2.1.4.1.6 0l9.2-10.5c.4-.4 1-.5 1.4-.1l1.5 1.3c.4.4.5 1 .1 1.4L10.9 19.3c-.4.5-.9.7-1.5.7z">
   </path>
  </svg>
  <span aria-hidden="true" class="BpkCheckbox_bpk-checkbox__label__1vrLS BpkCheckbox_bpk-checkbox__label--small__16XBT">
   1 interchange
  </span>
 </label>
 <span class="BpkText_bpk-text__2NHsO BpkText_bpk-text--sm__345aT FiltersCheckboxes_subText__3aG9- FiltersCheckboxes_block__1ZTpQ FiltersCheckboxes_checkboxIndent__2c49O">
  2 787 $
 </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you check for iframes?

Answer (score 0):

With this

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('BpkCheckbox_bpk-checkbox__label__1vrLS BpkCheckbox_bpk-checkbox__label--small__16XBT')
```

you picked two class names as one (between every class name is a space).
Try using this:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('BpkCheckbox_bpk-checkbox__label__1vrLS')
```

By the way- this

```
driver.find_element_by_name('2+ interchanges').click()
```

is searching for the name in an element (eg ), not the value within. (Your tag has no name attribute)

Comment: Thank you @maor10, but still no luck, because this class name, occurs several times(yes i forgot to wrote it before, now is fixed code)

Comment: Try using driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@value='2+ interchanges']") - if the only thing you know about the element is it's value

Answer (score 0):

All right i found it :)
Solution, i just added wait for 10 secs before click, and changed xpath.

```
time.sleep(10)
stops_chkbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="stops_content"]/div/div/div[3]/label').click()
```